# Pass data from View controller to tableViewController

Tags: swift, tableview

I have two view Controllers, the second one I embedded a table view controller with static cell in a ViewContainter.

How I can pass the data in the first view controller to populate the table view controller.

my View Controller as in image
[my View Controller as in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzadU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have two viewControllers, **FirstViewController** and **SecondTableViewController**.
Create a segue identifier for embedded segue in your storyboard lets say "**SecondTableViewControllerContainerSegue**"

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
  private var someValueFromFirstVC = 5
  private var childContainerController:SecondTableViewController?

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "SecondTableViewControllerContainerSegue"){
        self.childContainerController = segue.destination as? SecondTableViewController
        self.childContrainerController.someValueFromSecondVc = someValueFromFirstVC
    }
  }
}
```

If your problem is more specific let me know i will update accordingly.

Comment: Is the segue "SecondTableViewControllerContainerSegue" from  FirstViewController to SecondTableViewController or versa?

Comment: Its from container on first controller to SecondTableController